# How to convert Lambda Expression to SQL Server Query syntax?

Tags: t-sql, linq-to-sql

Here's the lambda expression, I want to convert this to SQL Server query syntax.

```
{x => ((True AndAlso x.Name.ToLower().Contains("_")) AndAlso Not(x.IsDeleted))}
```

Note : The lambda expression is equivalent to Where Clause of Sql server.
I want to convert it to sql syntax and then pass it to sql server stored procedure.
Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: "True", "AndAlso", and "Not" are all Visual Basic keywords, why did you tag this question with C#-4.0?

Comment: Why would you want to convert this to T-SQL?  Are you using linq-to-sql or are you using t-sql?  I'd recommend trying to understand what is required to be queried within sql server (t-sql) rather than "converting" something.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you can use the `ToString` method on the `IQueryable` object returned by the LINQ statement to find the exact query that would be executed on the database.  But, in this case, I would guess something like this might be generated for the WHERE:

```
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, '_') AND NOT IsDeleted
```

But, you haven't provided any detail that would allow me to verify that.

If you don't have full-text on, then the following might be more applicable:

```
WHERE Name like '%_%' AND NOT IsDeleted
```

Comment: Might want to mention that `CONTAINS` requires full text search.